# 'target.html()' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of a certain character (quotes) from an element. My code works fine in Chrome and FF but fails in IE with the debugger saying - `'target.html()' is null or not an object`

here is what my code looks like -

```
text = "some random text";
target = $('#target');
target.append(text);
target.html(target.html().replace(/"/g, " "));
```

What's causing that error in IE and how do i fix it?

Comment: IE  may not like `target` and it may be part of `window.target`.  Instead, use `var $target = $("#target")` and use `$target` from then on.  Just a guess, though.

Comment: @ExplosionPills the actual var name is not target i just used it for example. That steers away the possibility of var name causing trouble

Comment: Make a demo with the problem on JSFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wYvDe/ 
But it looks like jsfiddle.net itself gives a handful of errors in IE8 (or at least for me)

Answer (score 2):

'target' is used an attribute and IE does not like it if you use it  as a variable name. In fact it even refuses to recognize `event.target` and insists on `event.srcElement` (tell me about it ..) .

Anyways, it should work if you rename the object to `$target`.

Comment: Additionally, you can also set attr('disabled', 'disabled') for those picky browsers which won't allow hide on the option tag.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons I get such errors is because the HTML is not correctly formed(and it sure gave me hell before I found out). Other browsers allow a missing '>' or other syntactical errors, but IE is very strict.

So just see minutely that the markup in target.html() is correct.